# Cannot resolve module on using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to setup jest for my project.

### Project structure

```
root/
    src/ 
        index.ts 
    test/ 
        index.spec.ts 
    package.json 
    babel.config.cjs
```

#### index.ts

```
const sum = (num1: number, num2: number): number => {
  return num1 + num2;
};

export { sum };
```

#### index.spec.ts

```
import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { sum } from "./index";

describe("Testing index", () => {
  test("Should be 3 on 1+2", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });

  test("Should not be 5 on 1+2", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).not.toBe(5);
  });
});
```

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDirs": [
            "src",
            "test"
        ],
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@": ["src/*"]
        },
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode"
    ]
}
```

#### babel.config.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this? I know that there is some issue with `tsconfig.json` or maybe I need to add something to my jest configuration. I tried clearing the jest cache but it does not work. Problem is import statement is not being resolved by jest. But it works fine normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be following the official Jest examples, which assume the `.spec.js` files are directly into the `src` folder. But it's not your case: you have a separate `test/` folder.

So you have to import with `../src/index` instead:

```js
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'
import {sum} from '../src/index'

describe('Testing index', () => {
  test('Should be 3 on 1+2', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
  })

  test('Should not be 5 on 1+2', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).not.toBe(5)
  })
})
```

Comment: if you have no respect for my [Whitesmiths style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style), I can't have any for yours

Comment: @MisterJojo well, that's _my_ answer, so I'll use my indentation style.

Comment: In that case, why do you allow yourself to change the indentation style of others in their own answers?

Comment: TBH, I didn't know of this style and though it was badly formatted, and I can't find the answer you are talking about - I guess it was on another question. Cheers.